# Ubercart shipments are not entities

Tags: 7, ubercart, entities

So I am interested in logging signed, scanned copies of my Ubercart packing slips.  Cool right?  The problem is that Ubercart shipments are not fieldable entities.  Thus I cannot add a file field or even a checkbox to say that I received a signed packing slip.

My plan was to make an entity called 'Signed Packing Slip' with the file field and use [entity reference](https://drupal.org/project/entityreference) to link it to at least uc_order (because, again I can't link up with Ubercart Shipments because they are not entities).

Can anyone think of a hack or workaround to make this work?  Is there any way to incorporate custom PHP code or database calls through ECK/EntityReference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Migrate to commerce. ;)

I think you'll have to do this the old manual way.

1. Create your own entity with an image field to store the data.
2. Hook_form_alter the relevant form to insert your own widget.
3. Handle form submission, and push the data to it's relevant entity, then hand over form submission to the original handler.